# Laravel jQuery is not defined, no defer in script tag

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, webpack

In my app.js file, jQuery is defined:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

console.log($); //works fine
```

My app.js is processed by webpack and laravel mix, and loaded from the public folder:

```
    <!-- Scripts -->    
    <script src="{{ asset('themes/metajibe/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Notice there is no `defer`. I even moved it from the bottom of the `app.blade.php` to up in the `<head>`. However, if I run some custom javascript on a template, `$` is undefined, as is `jQuery`. They are both defined in the console after the page loads. Once again, I can write my custom javascript in the mix app.js, and use jQuery just fine, but I want this to only run on a specific page to adjust some UI. Thoughts?

Comment: Isn't jquery already required in `bootstrap.js`? `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`

Comment: I'm using a laravel theme built with bootstrap, and this is how the app.js is already configured (I didn't add the `import`)

Comment: Might be that you are calling a jQuery function before including the js file?

Comment: you could try to use the `mix()` helper instead of asset ? (which depends on the versioning of assets) Otherwise do you mind showing us your `webpack.mix.js` file?